# PHP is inserting two duplicate rows in MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having trouble with PHP and MYSQL. I have an HTML form which when submitted runs the following PHP script.The problem is that the following PHP code is inserting the data into the database twice. I think it is something to do with the following PHP and not the database:

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST['firstname'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
$display_name = $_POST['displayname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$add_line1 = $_POST['addline1'];
$add_line2 = $_POST['addline2'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$county = $_POST['county'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO members (memberID, 
memberPassword, 
memberFirstName, 
memberLastName,
memberAddressLine1, 
memberAddressLine2, 
memberCity,
memberCounty, 
memberPostcode, 
memberDisplayName) 
VALUES ('$email', 
'$password', '$first_name', '$last_name',
 '$add_line1', '$add_line2','$city',
 '$county', '$postcode', '$display_name')";

if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
echo 'Guest Added';
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

You have `mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` in your code twice. Once in the if(), and once outside. Each of these will insert into your database.

The point to note here is that the `mysqli_query` inside the if is evaluated - that is, it is run and the if statement executes on the result of the function call. Thus, you do not need to call it again.

Comment: Yes; `mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` can be removed and just add `else{}` to the `if`-statement and there echo the 'Guest Added' message', as an indicator of success.

Comment: Thanks for you help - didn't realise it ran when being evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Tushar pointed out the twin mysqli queries and he is right, besides that, the code as is now will cause you security troubles since it allows sql injection...

Please modify your code as follows:

```
 $first_name   = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['firstname']);
 $last_name    = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lastname']);
 $display_name = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['displayname']);
 $email        = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
 $password     = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
 $add_line1    = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['addline1']);
 $add_line2    = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['addline2']);
 $city         = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['city']);
 $county       = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['county']);
 $postcode     = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST['postcode']);
```

Comment: Great advice - new to PHP and good to know practices regarding security.